# BlackBerry7 Maps support Voice Navigation

Tags: blackberry, maps

Does BlackBerry7's default map application supports Voice Navigation?

I found [BlackBerry Traffic](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/13110/?lang=en) which supports Text Navigation as well Voice Navigation but it does not contain Maps.
Is There Any API which gives us Voice Navigation?

Or if inbuilt BlackBerry Map app support with Voice Navigation would be great and if Voice Navigation is not supported by app then please provide me link saying that it is not supported.